# I cant install audio drivers for the jam 96k. I am prompted with an install error message

Tags: driver

(Imn not really into tech so I may be completely wrong )I'm trying to download audio drivers for the Jam 96k. It is a pretty old device but there are drivers available for them. I am running windows 11, once I go to install the driver I am presented with an install error:
"a required certificate is not within its validity period when verifying against the current system clock or the timestamp in the signed file."
Im guessing it has to do with the publisher certificate being expired ( if that is a thing ). Does anyone know how to solve this issue? [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PB0zU.png)

---

.inf file:

```
; MyDriver.inf
;
; Installs WinUsb
;

[Version]
Signature = "$Windows NT$"
Class     = USBDevice
ClassGUID = {88BAE032-5A81-49f0-BC3D-A4FF138216D6}
Provider = %ManufacturerName%
CatalogFile=MicPlus-JAM96k-MiC96k.cat
DriverVer = 11/21/2017,16.18.33.346

; ========== Manufacturer/Models sections ===========

[Manufacturer]
%ManufacturerName% = Standard,NTamd64

[Standard.NTamd64]
"JAM96k" = USB_Install, USB\VID_0C60&PID_0019
"MiC96k" = USB_Install, USB\VID_0C60&PID_001B
"MiC Plus" = USB_Install, USB\VID_0C60&PID_0025

; =================== Installation ===================

[USB_Install]
Include=winusb.inf
Needs=WINUSB.NT

[USB_Install.Services]
Include=winusb.inf
AddService=WinUsb,0x00000002,WinUsb_ServiceInstall

[WinUsb_ServiceInstall]
DisplayName     = %WinUsb_SvcDesc%
ServiceType     = 1
StartType       = 3
ErrorControl    = 1
ServiceBinary   = %12%\WinUSB.sys

[USB_Install.HW]
AddReg=Dev_AddReg

[Dev_AddReg]
; By default, USBDevice class uses iProduct descriptor to name the device in
; Device Manager on Windows 8 and higher.
; Uncomment for this device to use %DeviceName% on Windows 8 and higher:
;HKR,,FriendlyName,,%DeviceName%
HKR,,DeviceInterfaceGUIDs,0x10000,"{$devinterfaceGuidRegistryFormat$}"

[USB_Install.CoInstallers]
AddReg=CoInstallers_AddReg
CopyFiles=CoInstallers_CopyFiles

[CoInstallers_AddReg]
;


[CoInstallers_CopyFiles]
;


[DestinationDirs]
CoInstallers_CopyFiles=11

; ================= Source Media Section =====================

[SourceDisksNames]
1 = %DiskName%

[SourceDisksFiles]
;


; =================== Strings ===================

[Strings]
ManufacturerName="Apogee"
ClassName="Universal Serial Bus devices"
DiskName="Apogee Installation Disk"
WinUsb_SvcDesc="WinUSB Driver"
REG_MULTI_SZ = 0x00010000
```

I was expecting to download the drivers.

Comment: Typically, when a driver package is created, the manufacturer signs it with their certificate, along with a certified timestamp.  As long as the certificate was valid at the time of the timestamp, it lives forever.  If they forgot the timestamp, then the package expires when the certificate expires.  That would be a bone-headed error.  You might check with the manufacturer.

Comment: The Jam+ is not supposed to need a driver.  Does it not just plug-and-play?

Comment: @TimRoberts I believe that its native to iOS devices, for windows it instructs to download drivers. Thanks for the help, I'll try reaching the support team about the error, only issue is that the Jam I'm using isn't listed in their support page :/ .